# How to make AND condition in SQL optional

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
    usp_demo_sp '2016-04-01',@EmpIDs
    usp_demo_sp '2016-04-01','111,222,333'

Query:
        select * from tbl_bill a, temp b
        where a.emplid=b.emplid
        and a.emplid in (select * from dbo.SplitString(REPLACE(replace(@EmpIDs,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'' ),CHAR(9),''), ','))
```

In the above stored procedure I am using the above query.
@empids parameter are comma separated values.
This query is working fine for single or multiple empids.
But I need to implement condition such that when @EmpIDs is null or '' then I need to remove below condition

```
 and a.emplid in (select * from dbo.SplitString(REPLACE(replace(@EmpIDs,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'' ),CHAR(9),''), ','))
```

from the above query.
Please suggest the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from tbl_bill a
join temp b
    on a.emplid=b.emplid
where ltrim(rtrim(isnull(@EmpIDs, ''))) = '' 
OR a.emplid in (
    select * 
    from dbo.SplitString(REPLACE(replace(@EmpIDs,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'' ),CHAR(9),''), ',')
)
```

Note that I've changed your implicit join to an explicit join.

Comment: Yes..Perfect.. It is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But due to OR condition it is taking more time to execute I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tbl_bill a, 
     inner join temp b on a.emplid = b.emplid
where (a.emplid is null
       or
       a.emplid = ''
       or
       a.emplid in (select * 
                    from dbo.SplitString(REPLACE(replace(@EmpIDs,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'' ),CHAR(9),''), ','))
         )
```